# Aligning Python list/array address before passing on to C for processing

Tags: python, alignment, ctypes

Trying to align Python array/list address before passing it on to C for processing

Writing a few functions in C to be called from Python 3.6+ and am wondering how to ensure alignment (32,64,128,...) of an array/list memory address before passing its address over to C to take advantage of AVX2, SSE2 etc...

What I have already works fine. No problems with how things are working. No. I'm just wondering:

In the C functions (gcc) I can do (and seems to work fine looking at the generated assembly code):

```
__attribute__((aligned(32))) int *a = array; // array passed in from Python
```

and then I'm writing the accommodating C code for optimization by gcc ... It works for my needs. Yes. But is there a way to do this (alignment) beforehand on the Python side?

Comment: Your C code isn't going to make GCC adjust the alignment of `array`. GCC can't do that. I'm pretty sure your code is UB. Also, lists store `PyObject *`s, and it's pretty hard to do anything SIMD with those regardless of alignment, especially since the pointed-to objects aren't going to have any alignment guarantees you manage to force upon the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ctypes align data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155164/python-ctypes-align-data-structure)

Comment: The Possible Duplicate link is just the answer I looking for!

Comment: You can close / mark your question as a dupe of the other one.